# Finding who is whose manager from the given table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have given the required table and resultant table below. Give query for SQL server 2005.

```
------------------
ID    Name     Mgr
------------------
1    Ajay      4
2    Vijay     5
3    Nayeem    1
4    Rakesh    3
5    Varun     4
6    Bhupesh   1
-----------------
```

I want the result as

```
-----------------
Name     Mgr
-----------------
Ajay     Rakesh
Vijay    Varun
Nayeem   Ajay
Rakesh   Nayeem
Varun    Rakesh
Bhupesh  Ajay
```

Comment: What have you tried? And why did you make this CW? But most importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: Something wrong with your sample data. You have Nayeem manage by Rakesh but Rakesh is managed by Nayeem -- never seen a recurssive org chart before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select sub.name , sup.name 
from yourtab sub
join yourtab sup
on sup.id = sub.mgr
```

;

Comment: Your query is almost correct after doing changing last line.Select sub.name , sup.name  
from yourtab sub 
join yourtab sup 
on sup.mgr = sub.id

Comment: Hello Dear, I got my solution from the above query, but i am not clear with one thing. If we are writing the on condition as sub.mgr = sup.id, i mean the reverse of the last line of the query the result is something else, whats the reason behind that